Why does empty($object->arrayProperty) result in true while array elements are set and filled?
Without any other changes the following three lines in the same spot result in (for me) incomprehensible results. The first result in my head does not match to what the other lines return:
var_dump(empty($this->table)); //results in "bool(true)"

var_dump($this->table); //results in an array of 75 elements

var_dump(empty($this->table[0])); //results in "bool(false)"

First of all:

My question is NOT what to do, to make my code work. Many other topics explain this very good and I don't want duplication here.

My question is NOT why PHP has an error here. As PHP is what it is and it is the behaviour that it is.

As !isset() for non-false elements is an equivalent to empty() in this case it obviously has same results. I could have interchanged "...does empty($array) result in true..." inside the title with "...why does an array not exist...". I decided for more specific wording.


I search for the explanation that leads to this (at least for me) confusing result. I have a guess that it might be a mechanic related to __get() or ob_get_clean() but I have no real clue how these work internally.
The Environment:

I have a method inside an object that extracts an array out of a csv-file. (changed names)

   $object = new Class();
   
   empty($object->method()); //results in false - as I would expect as an array with 75 elements is returned


I wrap this together with other variables of different types into a params-array.

   $params =['table' => $object->method(),...];
   
   empty($params['table']); //still results in false here


Via a View object I pass the params-array to a view

   return (new View('transactions/show',$params))->render();

For the passing inside the View object I use the __get magic method
   public function __get(string $name) {
      return $this->params[$name] ?? null;
   }

The render function includes the view with output buffering
   public function render() {
       ob_start();
       include VIEW_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->view . '.php';
       return ob_get_clean();
   }


Inside the view ('transactions/show') I am able to access the params by $this->variable and as mentioned above the array is accessible and working fine but the result "true" of the empty($this->table) confuses me.

All my testing lead me to the point that step 3. is responsible for the results I experience inside step 4.
To show a reproducible version hereafter complete files:
Controller class:
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Model\DemoClass;
use App\View;

class Demo {
    public function index() {
        $object = new DemoClass();

        empty($object->demoMethod()); //results in false - as I would expect as an array with 75 elements is returned

        $params =['table' => $object->demoMethod()];

        empty($params['table']); //still results in false here

        return (new View('demo/show',$params))->render();
    }
}

The Model class (here only simulating to get an array of arrays from a source (csv, Database, whereever)
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Model;

class DemoClass {
    public function demoMethod() {
        $array = [
            [1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6],
            [7, 8, 9],
        ];
        return $array;
    }
}

the View class (only the needed excerpt):
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App;

use Framework\Exception\ViewNotFoundException;

class View {

    public function __construct(protected string $view, protected array $params =[]) {
    }

    public static function make(string $view, array $params =[]): static {
        return new static($view, $params);
    }
    
    public function render(): string {
        $viewPath = VIEW_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->view . static::PHP_TYPE;
        
        if(!file_exists($viewPath)) {
            throw new ViewNotFoundException();
        }
        ob_start();
        include $viewPath;
        return (string) ob_get_clean();
    }
    
    public function __get(string $name) {
        return $this->params[$name] ?? null;
    }

    public function __toString():string {
        return $this->render();
    }
}

The view/html - kept it short without HTML header (it makes no difference here)
<?= var_dump(empty($this->table)); //results in "bool(true)" ?>
</br>

<?= var_dump($this->table); //results in an array of 75 elements ?>
</br>

<?= var_dump(empty($this->table[0])); //results in "bool(false)" ?>
</br>

with calling the Demo->index() (e.g. via Router) the result is:
bool(true)
array(3) { 
    [0]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> int(1) 
        [1]=> int(2) 
        [2]=> int(3) 
    } 
    [1]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> int(4) 
        [1]=> int(5) 
        [2]=> int(6) 
    } 
    [2]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> int(7) 
        [1]=> int(8) 
        [2]=> int(9) 
    } 
}

bool(false)

I didn't read this wall of code through but suppose you didn't implement __isset()

Also, I would advise against using empty() in general. If you were using $this->table === [] instead of empty() you'd have not a single problem.

thanks a lot for reading and answering - as explained inside this wall of text and code (I used Staging Ground here - that lead to this mass of text and code at the end) I have the solutions for my problem and the question is not how to avoid but why the empty() has this result. Therefore it is more of a request for explanation but for solution but thx again.

I tested to include __isset() to View class. This results in both empties hitting this magic method and resulting in true. I know empty sometimes serves with unexpected results so I will not bother here why exactly that is. The question still remaining is:
Why does the third empty request (empty($this->table[0])) result in false when it does not hit an __isset() while the first does not? Either way I would expect both results to be the same.

I sort of get you, the question is why empty doesn't stop on the name when it appears empty and proceeds to checking name[0].

And it seems the answer is simply "well, it doesn't stop".

I guess my question is a little bit different. As far as I know empty() does the same as !isset($var) || $var == false . The missing __isset() obviously results in a !isset($var) == false (otherwise both would directly result in true as they would stop). That means $var ==false&& $var[0] == true, right? Thats what I am not understanding...
At least I totally understand why with existing __isset() there is the same result (That is because both cases stop when the first part results in true).

forget about empty. It's isset which is in effect here. And your question boils down to why $obj->prop is not set and $obj->prop[0] is. Taken separately, both of these are quite expected and documented. The only question, why isset moves on to check  $obj->prop[0] already knowing that  $obj->prop is not set.

@YourCommonSense that's most likely because when the property is not accessible directly empty($obj->prop) tries to call __isset() magic method but empty($obj->prop[0]) tries to call __get() magic method and proceed as if the parameter was array.

Or rather. If the __isset() magic method is present the empty($obj->prop[0]) will use it. But if it's not present it skips the __isset() check and goes directly to __get().

Thank you Michal Hynčica, this is my answer! I was not aware about this behaviour. I still wonder why but as mentioned in my topic, PHP is what it is. Thank you all very much!

Please push it as an answer so that I can accept it.
